# How can i write onCreateView as onViewCreated

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);

    }
```

I have this code for my fragment but it doesn't let me use findViewById so I want to make it onViewCreated but it has some container and tab in it so can anyone help me?

Comment: You should write `view.findViewById.` before the return statement else the `code would be unreachable`

Comment: Thanks @SantanuSur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use getView() or the View parameter from implementing the onViewCreated method. It returns the root view for the fragment (the one returned by onCreateView() method). With this also you can use findViewById().

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.foo);
}
```

As getView() works only after onCreateView(), you can't use it inside onCreate() or onCreateView() methods of the fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Like @SantanuSur said

> You should write view.findViewById. before the return statement else the code would be unreachable

problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

`onCreateView` is called when the view is created. Here you do things to setup the view.
`onViewCreated` is called after the view has been created. Here you can set values and do other stuff.

This is explained in the api reference [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html).

Comment: I just added `view` before it